# Online-accounts not recognized by gnome-shell-google-calendar

Tags: 13.04, online-accounts, google-calendar

Hey everybody I'm running Ubuntu 13.04, and everything works fine, except when I'm trying to implement the `gnome-shell-google-calendar` according to [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/google-calendar-gnome-shell-integration.html) guide.

It works, except that my online-accounts are not recognized (although set up).

```
Please choose the Account: None
You have entered an invalid account number. Please enter an integer.
Logging in as 'None'...
Error logging in as 'None'
'None' may not be a GNOME online account. A list of existing accounts is below.
If you do not see a list of accounts, then you first need to add one.
For more information, see http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/accounts.html
Please choose the Account:
```

what's the reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, I found the solution for anybody with the same problem:

in a terminal run:

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center
```

Then there should be 2 online-account settings;

if you add a google-online account to the second one (the one that looks like a plug) the script recognizes the google account

Comment: I only see one online account setting and it's the one that looks like a plug. I already added my google account to that and the .py script recognized the account, but then I get error `Error logging in as 'whoami@gmail.com' 'whoami@gmail.com' may not be a GNOME online account.`. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I guess this is a bug related to Ubuntu 13.04. My other apps which use the online accounts have stopped working too.

When launching the script manually, the following stacktrace is thrown:

```
Logging in as 'xxx@gmail.com'...
Error logging in as 'xxx@gmail.com'
'xxx@gmail.com' may not be a GNOME online account. A list of existing accounts is below.
If you do not see a list of accounts, then you first need to add one.
For more information, see http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/accounts.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./gnome-shell-google-calendar.py", line 477, in <module>
account = oauth.oauth_prompt()
File "/home/tnaessens/gnome-shell-google-calendar/oauth.py", line 13, in oauth_prompt
'/org/gnome/OnlineAccounts')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
'su', (bus_name, flags)))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.OnlineAccounts was not provided by any .service files
```

When I went looking in the dbus-1/services directory, there was no org.gnome.OnlineAccounts.

***Solution:*** I fixed this by downloading `gnome-online-accounts` and by restarting the .py file. It asked for my account, I entered it and it immediatly started synchronizing.

Comment: didn't solve my problem unfortunately, since no online-accounts are recognized at all. So the 
    logging in as: 'xxx.gmail.com' doesn't work for me at all